# Getting UnityException: Launching iOS project via Xcode4 failed

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I am trying to port unity project but its giving me this error " Getting UnityException: Launching iOS project via Xcode4 failed. " . I have also using Xcode 5 & Unity 4.2 for this compilation.Please let me know how can i solve this issue.Its little bit creating frustation me.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and found answer here:

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/200437-Unity-4-2-0f4-and-Xcode-5-not-working
and here
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/539677/ios-7-and-xcode5.html

Short answer is:

1. Build project in Unity 4.2
2. In Xcode open File/Open Recent/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj
3. In project go to Build Settings/Build Options/Debug Information Format and set it to DWARF

Hope this helps! ;)

P.S. Unfortunately this has helped only partially. Build and run still don't work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm not sure what did the trick, but it was probably a setting under:

> Unity Preferences -> External Tools -> iOS Xcode 4.x support *[untick]*